# Segmentation Fault (R.stamp) - "no private recovery resources for TARGET_DEVICE"

Tags: android, segmentation-fault, makefile, r.java-file

While I am trying to compile an android application from my build space, i am getting the following error:

> No private recovery resources for TARGET_DEVICE sabresd_6dq

```
make:Entering directory '/home/juvin/gitcode/code/'
target R.java/Manifest.java: SampleApp (out/target/common/obj/APPS/SampleApp_intermediates/src/R.stamp)

make: *** [out/target/common/obj/APPS/SampleApp_intermediates/src/R.stamp]

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

make: Leaving directory '/home/juvin/gitcode/code'
```

This one is happening when i try to compile using `mm` command.
I can see that other applications, iam able to build this way without any error.
I can also see that this same app is working with eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is ,
I was using a different version of eclipse and sdk to compile. so the same code i was unable to compile in my build setup.
i just removed the "menu", "values-xxx" folders from the project. and worked like charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the "out" directory and delete the corresponding output files:

> > out/target/product/xxx/data/app$ rm *.apk